# How to get the title of an article using regex?

Tags: regex, simple-html-dom

I want to get the title of an article from this page using regex and simplehtmldom :  http://laperuanavegana.wordpress.com/about/

in this case title is : Cómo preparar SEITÁN

Here is my regex :

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
preg_match_all("title=(.*?)",$html->innertext,$title);
echo "this is title ".$title[0][0]."<br>";
```

It would be helpful if anyone help me to find the bug.

Comment: [You shouldn't try to parse HTML with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to look for text between `<title>` and `</title>`, not for text following `title=`.

For example:

```
$html = "Sometext<title>Seitan</title>More text";
preg_match_all('|<title>(.*?)</title>|',$html,$title);
echo "this is title ".$title[1][0]."<br>";
```